# error in the application output while using qt creator

Tags: qt, user-interface, opencv, compiler-errors

I have pasted the application output in the below link.please go through it and give me necessary suggestions to get my code working.
  https://pastebin.com/xaFEBrDY

```
The program has unexpectedly finished and crashed.
```

the code had gtk errors which stated the use of both 2nd & 3rd version but after adding the path and libraries of gtk2 and removing gtk3 gave the above errors. can anyone help me out in knowing, what I have missed. thanks in advance

Comment: In the first line you can see this: "Error in `/home/build-FYP-Desktop_87a068-Debug/FYP': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000660b60". So, it seems that you pass uninitialized or wrong pointer in `realloc()`.

Comment: i am a newbie in using qt creator. could you help me out to how to initialize that pointer and how to find its exact location

Comment: We don't see your code, so we can't tell you where you need to fix wrong call of `realloc()`. Try to make as small as possible program, and show us the code.

Comment: i am using qt-5.8 version and i tries using #include<Qexception> as well. but it shows error as file not found. and i have tried using #include<Qconcurrentexception> with using concuurent::exception and stille the errors persist

Comment: There are no `Qexception`, so you need to write `#include <QException>` (not `#include <Qexception>`)

Comment: I have written the same as  u mentioned.@llya. similar errors occur for #include<Qtcore> and others

Comment: Why do you write `#include<Qtcore>` instead of `#include<QtCore>`?

Comment: i have written it as u have mentioned. but the problem still persists and says "no such file or directory"